# Using Staticresouce in Visual State causes Blend Designer to break: "Invalid attribute value Unknow for property Background"

Tags: xaml, designer, blend, uwp, visualstates

I'm trying to change the Background of a Grid by using a Visual State and a Staticresouce as the value in the Setter of the Visual State. It works just fine at Runtime but  the designer shows the following error (which doesn't help me a lot):

---

Exception: Der Text zu diesem Fehlercode wurde nicht gefunden. (unknown error)

Stacktrace: 
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.XamlUIPresenter.Render()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsUIXamlImageHost.RenderWorker()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsUIXamlImageHost.RenderScheduler.OnRender(Object object)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Views.WindowsUIXamlImageHost.RenderScheduler.b__26_0(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Invalid attribute value Unknown for property Background.
InnerException: None

---

This is what I tried:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TestGroup">
             <VisualState x:Name="TestState">
                  <VisualState.Setters>
                       <Setter Target="grid.(Panel.Background)" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" />
                  </VisualState.Setters>
             </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>


<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
</ResourceDictionary>


<App>
    ...
    <App.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
              <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Test.xaml"/>
              </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </App.Resources>
</App>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current *Blend* is really buggy so I am not surprised if you see errors like this.

One workaround is, reopen your page that contains this resource in Blend. You should see a dialog popping up (see below image). Then select your **Test.xaml** file from the *Available dictionaries* dropdown and hit OK.

[image]

By doing so blend will generate a **DesignTimeResources.xaml** file under your project *Properties* and it should eliminate the error on the designer.

---

However, I also noticed that your `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` isn't wrapped within a `<ResourceDictionary>`. Shouldn't it be something like this instread?

```
<App.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Test.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</App.Resources>
```

---

### Update

This is indeed a Blend bug which even happens with built-in resources. To replicate, try building the project and then go to the *States* tab and select a `VisualState`, right after you will see the Blend Designer crashed. Note that I have *Run project code in XAML Designer (if supported)* turned off.

Currently the only way to remove the crash is to reopen the xaml file.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. So this is not a mistake of mine but a bug in Blend? This would be great news because it's akward defining all those setters without the designer just by typing them in.
The missing ResourceDictionary is just a copy-paste error, I removed all the unnecessary parts, sry.

Comment: If it works, then it could be a Blend bug. I'm not exactly sure how you structure your files but the issue seems to be that Blend couldn't locate that *Test.xaml* resource dictionary file. However, I just tried to create a demo project and did exactly what you described, it worked fine. Blend didn't complain.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error message. I even tried it with a build-in resource and still the same error.

Comment: `BackgroundAltBrushMedium` is not a built-in resource is it? Try using another `ThemeResource` instead.

Comment: Added another screenshot, still the same error.
I just picked BackgroundAltBrushMedium from the resources I could pick on the property window while editing the Visual State so I guess it is, I haven't defined a resource with this key.

Comment: No, that's also wrong. You should be using a `Brush` instead of `Color`.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad. Now it should be right but the error's still there.

Comment: I'd suggest you to try removing parts in your project to locate what the issue really is. Is it a new project? Is it a project that migrated from earlier version of WinRT?

Comment: I copied parts of an old WinRT project but the project itself was created a week ago using Visual Studio 2015 RTM. I'll create a fresh project and try it out.

Comment: Yeah, what I also noticed is that in the new uwp, we have `<Application x:Class="xxx.App" ...>` but you have `<App ...`, not sure if that would cause any issue though.

Comment: Another copy-paste mistake.
So I've created a fresh new project. I've done nothing but adding a VisualState with the Setter from the screenshot above. After building the project and selecting the Visual State in the state window of blend the exact same error occured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87162/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-cort3vl).